# How to create a ListPreference dialog to display in a non preference activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, listpreference

I want to display a ListPreference Dialog in a non Preference Activity.

Here's my the code that creates the Dialog

```
// this is my current activity
ListPreference listPreference = new ListPreference(this);   
listPreference.setDialogIcon(R.drawable.auto_download);
listPreference.setTitle(R.string.autoDownloadTitle);
listPreference.setEntries(R.array.autoDownloadEntries);
listPreference.setEntryValues(R.array.autoDownloadValues);
listPreference.setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
Dialog dialog = listPreference.getDialog();
```

My problem is that dialog is allways null...
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this kind of things, `Preference` should be in the `PreferenceScreen` and the activity must extend `PreferenceActivity`.

I think you want to implement a dialog that show the list of choices like `ListPreference` do. I recommend to use `AlertDialog` with list views (based on ArrayAdapter).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-to-display-list-view-in-alert-dialog-in-android) for example or [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) documentation.