# How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In an Android application, I want to display a custom list view in an AlertDialog.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just take List of strings, then create sequence of CharSequence[], then use AlertDialog.Builder to show the items. Here is the simplest example with snapshot http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/12/how-to-show-listview-in-android-alertdialog.html

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Used below code to display custom list in AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DialogActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");

builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
                builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
builderSingle.show();
```

Comment: is there any possibility to detect long clicks on this items? i'm looking for hours for a popup menu solution which works on all api levels

Comment: @Shvet supposedly, *show()* creates and shows the dialog, while *create()* only creates it.

Comment: How can I use this set up but instead of hardcoding my list, I need to get some data from parse that the user already have.?

Comment: @stanleysantoso create your own adapter, fill it with data, and then set it as the adapter for the alertdialog: dialogBuilder.setAdapter(MyCustomAdapter);  That should work

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything Thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: if I select one of the items, then close the dialog and reopen it, I can't see the previously selected radio button

Comment: What is the layout select_dialog_single_choice?

Comment: @ForceFieldsForDoors It's not a layout, it's a (ListView) resource inside the system dialog's layout. If you use `setMessage` on the builder, it will discard the ListView component. In order to show a list, you must keep from using setMessage.

Comment: what if I want title and subtitle for each item?

Comment: How can I set one of the radio button selected by default? Actually I need to save the user choice and select it when dialog opened again

Comment: get better than expect !

Answer (score 332):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList), there are three kinds of lists that can be used with an `AlertDialog`:

1. Traditional single-choice list
2. Persistent single-choice list (radio buttons)
3. Persistent multiple-choice list (checkboxes)

I will give an example of each below.

## Traditional single-choice list

The way to make a traditional single-choice list is to use `setItems`.

[image]

**Java version**

```
// setup the alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Choose an animal");

// add a list
String[] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
builder.setItems(animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case 0: // horse
            case 1: // cow
            case 2: // camel
            case 3: // sheep
            case 4: // goat
        }
    }
});

// create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

There is no need for an OK button because as soon as the user clicks on a list item control is returned to the `OnClickListener`.

**Kotlin version**

```
// setup the alert builder
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
builder.setTitle("Choose an animal")

// add a list
val animals = arrayOf("horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat")
builder.setItems(animals) { dialog, which ->
    when (which) {
        0 -> { /* horse */ }
        1 -> { /* cow   */ }
        2 -> { /* camel */ }
        3 -> { /* sheep */ }
        4 -> { /* goat  */ }
    }
}

// create and show the alert dialog
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()
```

## Radio button list

[image]

The advantage of the radio button list over the traditional list is that the user can see what the current setting is. The way to make a radio button list is to use `setSingleChoiceItems`.

**Java version**

```
// setup the alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Choose an animal");

// add a radio button list
String[] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
int checkedItem = 1; // cow
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(animals, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // user checked an item
    }
});

// add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // user clicked OK
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

// create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

I hard coded the chosen item here, but you could keep track of it with a class member variable in a real project.

**Kotlin version**

```
// setup the alert builder
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
builder.setTitle("Choose an animal")

// add a radio button list
val animals = arrayOf("horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat")
val checkedItem = 1 // cow
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(animals, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->
    // user checked an item
}


// add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
    // user clicked OK
}
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)

// create and show the alert dialog
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()
```

## Checkbox list

[image]

The way to make a checkbox list is to use `setMultiChoiceItems`.

**Java version**

```
// setup the alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Choose some animals");

// add a checkbox list
String[] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
boolean[] checkedItems = {true, false, false, true, false};
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(animals, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        // user checked or unchecked a box
    }
});

// add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // user clicked OK
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

// create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Here I hard coded the the which items in the list were already checked. It is more likely that you would want to keep track of them in an `ArrayList<Integer>`. See the [documentation example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) for more details. You can also set the checked items to `null` if you always want everything to start unchecked.

**Kotlin version**

```
// setup the alert builder
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
builder.setTitle("Choose some animals")

// add a checkbox list
val animals = arrayOf("horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat")
val checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(true, false, false, true, false)
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(animals, checkedItems) { dialog, which, isChecked ->
    // user checked or unchecked a box
}

// add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
    // user clicked OK
}
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)

// create and show the alert dialog
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()
```

## Notes

- For the `context` in the code above, don't use `getApplicationContext()` or you will get an `IllegalStateException` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304032/java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-custom-dialog) for why). Instead, get a reference to the activity context, such as with `this`.
- You can also populate the list items from a database or another source using [`setAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) or [`setCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCursor(android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener,%20java.lang.String)) or passing in a `Cursor` or `ListAdapter` into the `setSingleChoiceItems` or `setMultiChoiceItems`.
- If the list is longer than will fit on the screen then the dialog will automatically scroll it. If you have a really long list, though, I'm guessing that you should probably make a [custom dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) with [a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example/40584425#40584425).
- To test all of the examples above I just had a simple project with a single button than showed the dialog when clicked:

  ```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      Context context;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          context = this;
      }

      public void showAlertDialogButtonClicked(View view) {

          // example code to create alert dialog lists goes here
      }
  }
  ```

## Related

- [Android Alert Dialog with one, two, and three buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513919/android-alert-dialog-with-one-two-and-three-buttons)
  [image]
- [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742001/3681880)
  [image]

Comment: @AaA, I think you would need to make a [custom layout alert dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) that uses a `RecyclerView` in the layout for that.

Comment: what does the 'which' in dialog onclick method signify?

Comment: @gonephishing, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.content.DialogInterface,%20int)), it is "the button that was clicked (ex. `BUTTON_POSITIVE`) or the position of the item clicked".

Comment: What's the best way to make the above lists scrollable?

Comment: @LordDraagon, long lists will scroll automatically. See the Notes section above.

Comment: If you want to implement a simple list (1) with a custom adapter, use `Builder.setAdapter(ListAdapter, DialogInterface.OnClickListener)`: `which` in  listener's`onClick` will be equal to clicked item position. `Builder.setOnItemSelectedListener` will have no effect.

Answer (score 127):

You can use a custom dialog.

Custom dialog layout. `list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list)

ListView lv = (ListView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setTitle("ListView");
dialog.show();
```

Edit:

Using alertdialog

```
String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
alertDialog.setView(convertView);
alertDialog.setTitle("List");
ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
alertDialog.show();
```

custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @Juan - devtopia.coop you edited my post after upvoting just to downvote. Could you comment what is wrong

Comment: Nothing with the current version, the previous one was lacking all the adapter stuff and was therefor just showing an empty ListView, I gladly remove my negative vote now. I voted on an incomplete answer, not on this edit from 3 hours ago.

Comment: @Raghunandan , i used your code but i got exception on lv.setAdapter(adapter); line, can you help me?

Comment: @Ahmad what is the excpetion?

Comment: @Raghunandan Null Pointer Exception!

Comment: @Ahmad your listview object is null. See if you have initialized it properly

Comment: what is simple_list_item_1?

Comment: @stanleysantoso that layouts exits in the android framework

Comment: @stanleysantoso you can find the code @ http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/. You won't get a error unless there is something wrong with your code. Do check/post the same

Comment: Hey @Raghunandan ! Can you answer my question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777584/how-to-resize-an-alertdialog-builder/36777742?noredirect=1#comment61152133_36777742 thanks anyway!

Comment: Your second option is better. But how do I implement a click listener and get the item clicked.

Comment: Is it scrollable? @Raghunandan

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov yes it is scrollable. Listview will scroll

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried this approach and now I'm facing an issue. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41401928/6144372

Comment: @Raghunandan How would one go about doing as asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613942/

Answer (score 46):

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"A", "B", "C"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        // Do something with the selection
        mDoneButton.setText(items[item]);
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: What's m.DoneButton?

Comment: @ArhatBaid But setItems is not working when i put a message in setMessage. I searched in google but the answer i found was to set the message in setTitle. But the problem is setTitle only allows few number of characters. Is there a way to use setMessage and setItems in alert Dialog?

Comment: @David for that you have to go for custom dialog.

Comment: This solution is very nice because you can also go with a `ListAdapter` with `setSingleChoiceItems` (very similar to the call above)

Comment: Perfect as expected... handles hundreds of items with minimal code. :)

Answer (score 13):

This is how to show custom layout dialog with custom list item, can be customised as per your requirement.

[image]

STEP - 1 Create the layout of the DialogBox ie:-

**R.layout.assignment_dialog_list_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_round_corner_assignment_alert"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_popup_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:text="View as:"
        android:textColor="#4f4f4f" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_assignment_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

STEP - 2 Create custom list item layout as per your business logic

**R.layout.item_assignment_dialog_list_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_user_profile_image"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="ABCD XYZ" />
</LinearLayout>
```

STEP - 3 Create a Data model class of your own choice

```
public class AssignmentUserModel {

private String userId;
private String userName;
private String userRole;
private Bitmap userProfileBitmap;

public AssignmentUserModel(String userId, String userName, String userRole, Bitmap userProfileBitmap) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userRole = userRole;
    this.userProfileBitmap = userProfileBitmap;
}


public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

public Bitmap getUserProfileBitmap() {
    return userProfileBitmap;
}

public void setUserProfileBitmap(Bitmap userProfileBitmap) {
    this.userProfileBitmap = userProfileBitmap;
}

}
```

STEP - 4 Create custom adapter

```
public class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AssignmentUserModel> {
private final Context context;
private final List<AssignmentUserModel> userList;
   
public UserListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<AssignmentUserModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    userList = objects;
    this.context = context;
 }

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_assignment_dialog_list_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView profilePic = rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_profile_image);
    TextView userName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
    AssignmentUserModel user = userList.get(position);

    userName.setText(user.getUserName());

    Bitmap bitmap = user.getUserProfileBitmap();

    profilePic.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    return rowView;
}

}
```

STEP - 5 Create this function and provide ArrayList of above data model in this method

```
// Pass list of your model as arraylist
private void showCustomAlertDialogBoxForUserList(ArrayList<AssignmentUserModel> allUsersList) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.assignment_dialog_list_view);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); // this is optional
        }
        ListView listView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_assignment_users);
        TextView tv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_popup_title);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new UserListAdapter(context, R.layout.item_assignment_dialog_list_layout, allUsersList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, which, l) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "showAssignmentsList: " + allUsersList.get(which).getUserId());
           // TODO : Listen to click callbacks at the position
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Step - 6 Giving round corner background to dialog box

**@drawable/rectangle_round_corner_assignment_alert**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="16dp"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:top="16dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the "`import android.app.AlertDialog;`" import and then you write

```
    String[] items = {"...","...."};             
    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    build.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do stuff....
        }
    }).create().show();
```

Comment: you needed bc with create you build the AlertDialog the you show this then.

not the builder.

(c) Facebamm

Comment: @Facebamm that's not true. `show()` does both. `Calling this method is functionally identical to: AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.show();` that is directly from the `show()` method's documentation

Comment: that's right but sometimes i got some visibly user interfaces errors. (c) Facebamm

Comment: No, thats not true. show() is identical to create().show();         /**
         * Creates an {@link AlertDialog} with the arguments supplied to this
         * builder and immediately displays the dialog.
         * <p>
         * Calling this method is functionally identical to:
         * <pre>
         *     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         *     dialog.show();
         * </pre>
         */
        public AlertDialog show() {
            final AlertDialog dialog = create();
            dialog.show();
            return dialog;
        }

Comment: ok, i have tested for a while and I say sry, thats true.  (c) Facebamm

Answer (score 6):

This is too simple

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfile.this);

builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
            getCapturesProfilePicFromCamera();
        } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
            getProfilePicFromGallery();
        } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

As a beginner I would suggest you go through http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

I'll rundown what it basically does

1. Creates an XML file for the dialog and main Activity
2. In the main activity in the required place creates an object of android class [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
3. Adds custom styling and text based on the XML file
4. Calls the `dialog.show()` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually create a simple Array with Alert Dialog like this.

```kotlin
 val sexArray = arrayOf("Male", "Female")
 val selectedPosition = 0

 AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    .setSingleChoiceItems(sexArray, 0) { dialog, position ->
        val selectedSex = sexArray[position]
    }.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin:

```
fun showListDialog(context: Context){
    // setup alert builder
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setTitle("Choose an Item")

    // add list items
    val listItems = arrayOf("Item 0","Item 1","Item 2")
    builder.setItems(listItems) { dialog, which ->
        when (which) {
            0 ->{
                Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked Item 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            1->{
                Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked Item 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            2->{
                Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked Item 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    // create & show alert dialog
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: What sort of description?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it smoother to make a method to be called after the creation of the EditText unit in an AlertDialog, for general use?

```
public static void EditTextListPicker(final Activity activity, final EditText EditTextItem, final String SelectTitle, final String[] SelectList) {
    EditTextItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle(SelectTitle);
            builder.setItems(SelectList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                    EditTextItem.setText(SelectList[item]);
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void AlertDialogue(final List<Animals> animals) {
 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminActivity.this);
 alertDialog.setTitle("Filter by tag");

 final String[] animalsArray = new String[animals.size()];

 for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
  animalsArray[i] = tags.get(i).getanimal();

 }

 final int checkedItem = 0;
 alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(animalsArray, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

   Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + animalsArray[which]);

  }
 });


 AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
 alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 alert.show();

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.