# Setup Custom Dialog with ListView

Tags: android

I want to make a custom dialog with a listview.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj0MI.png)

I tried with Dialog and AlertDialog. I had these problems:

- In Dialog i can't set Adapter. Dialog is the closest to me but I must find the way to set adapter. Google gives me results about AlertDialog :/
- In AlertDialog, i can set Adapter, but I have problem with styling: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6KF.png)

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15762955/2215962

Comment: Thank you very much mate! my mistake was that i was doing `activity.findViewById` instead of `dialog.findViewById`... Now it works! That also helped me to remember the scope of variables. Here is what i was looking for: http://s12.postimg.org/6ct3jeqal/screenshot_15.png

Comment: no problem. Good Luck!