# Create AlertDialog with both MultiChoiceItems and message

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog where both a message (in a TextView, for instance) *and* a MultiChoice-list can be displayed at the same time, but I'm a bit lost as to how to do it.

Will I have to create my own subclass of AlertDialog, or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: You don't have to subclass AlertDialog. You can set the message using Builder.setMessage("Your message"). And for the multi-choice list you can refer the following link http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/making-a-list-coding-multiple-choice-list-dialogs.html

Comment: I believe this has been answered here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could create a normal AlertDialog but, instead of using the setMessage() method, you could just use a custom layout (you can inflate it in a View or even create a custom view) and use then the [setView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View)) method of the AlertDialog class.

Comment: But if I used a custom layout - would I still be able to call "setMultiChoiceItems" in the AlertDialog?

Comment: If you use a custom layout, you would not need to use it, but you can defer the logic elsewhere, but @iatsenko-anton answer would make your life much easier, I would say :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogFragment for customization

```
    public class ResponseDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        getDialog().getWindow()
                .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationFromDown;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        return dialog;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);
        //implement in layout what you want 
        return v;
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
    }
    }
}
```

for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html