# How to add 4 buttons to Material dialog according to design guidelines

Tags: android, material-design

As the title suggests, i require 4 action buttons(one of which is "Cancel") in a material dialog but there is provision of only 3.Is there any way to adjust 4 buttons while following the google design guidelines.

Comment: You can add a list, for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15762955/4503373

Comment: We don't cover this case explicitly in the Material spec, but it would be reasonable to follow the "Stacked full-width buttons" example from the [Dialogs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) section. If you end up with many more than four actions, however, you might consider using a scrollable list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to material design only 3 buttons can be added. As you said, one of your buttons is "Cancel", then I would like to suggest you to do this :-
Add three buttons on their respective places except the cancel one and use the setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel) method to use the cancel functionality on the dialog. You can then use onCanceledListener to detect for the cancel event on your dialog.

Comment: That seems the only option.Btw how about a cross button("X") on top right corner of dialog

Comment: You can have a ("X") button only with a  full-screen dialog app bar. See the link :- https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

Comment: The image which I want you to see is shown in the section titled "Full-screen dialog titles". On the right hand side of this title, the image is shown with a ("X") button.