# unable to select row in listview in a popup in 4.1 but working in android 5.0

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I have a popup in my page which has a listview. I have created design of popup in a seperate xml and loading it on some button click in my main page. The popup has a listview with each row having a image and a textview. I am not able to get row selection in listview in android 4.1 but it is working in 5.0. Can anyone please suggest me the solution?
Listview:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lstSites"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Listview Item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSite"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

adding row click listner:

```
lstSiteMenu = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.lstSites);

            adapter = new MenuItemsAdapter(SiteActivity.this, arrMenu);
            // Attach the adapter to a ListView
            lstSiteMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
            lstSiteMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        final int position, long id) {
            }
```

Comment: any error in logcat? when you say row selected you meant onItemClick not working or you are not getting position?

Comment: Remove this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

remove this property from listview , `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
and

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

from text and imageview.

And try This is sample example,

```
String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_file, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("List");
        ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        alertDialog.show();
```

otherwise your code is fine. it works.

go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog/15763023#15763023) for more details.

Another [official link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try all of solutions:

---

```
popupwindow.setFocusale(true);
listView xml : "android:focusable="true"
```

---

do not use `lstSiteMenu.setOnItemClickListener`
instead go to your Adapters `getView` and add

```
convertView.setOnClickListener
```

---

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from your `ListView`.

Also remove `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from your row layout in the `ImageView` and the `TextView`.

The list item is supposed to be clickable, there is disable it obtaining focus

Answer (score -1):

Set row onclick listener in adapter class

```
public class MenuItemsAdapter extends Base Adapter{
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             /*
                          Paste your adapter code
             */
              customView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("log", "You clicked at pos "+position);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

This code worked in all sdk versions.

Also remove these properties from xml files

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```