# Dialog is not working properly

Tags: android, dialog

I want to implement the following design:

[image: Screen Shot]

These five options are displayed on clicking an imageview.I am implementing this design using dialog.

**1.moreOption.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="View Contacts"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/archiveChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Archive Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deleteChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Delete Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/markAsUnread"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Mark as unread"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Email Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code that is displaying dialog on clicking imageview.

```
   ImageView imgMoreOption = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMoreoption);

   imgMoreOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_option);
           dialog.show();
       }
   });
```

Now on clicking imageview i am getting the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

But using dialog ,i am not getting according to the design given as from the top i ma getting much space .Please guide me how to implement the given design .

**Edited Code**

I have fixed the issue.Actually dialog was displaying the empty title.I have changed the code as given below:

```
imgMoreOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // hide the title bar
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_option);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

**moreOption.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="View Contacts"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/archiveChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Archive Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deleteChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Delete Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/markAsUnread"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Mark as unread"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:text="Email Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You dont have padings to top and bottom at your `TextView`-s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15763023/2826147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) While you're using the `weight`, its better if you change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` in your `TextView`s.

2) Add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` to remove the title bar/layout (the blanc space)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_option);
    dialog.show();
}
```

***PS:*** It's better if you use a fixed height of your `LinearLayout`, **or** a fixed height for the `TextView`s.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove your `Dialog`'s title bar.

use

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and for `TextView`s you can use one of android pre defined styles or your custom style

add this to your `TextView`s in xml file

```
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.pathfinder.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="View Contacts"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewContacts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/archiveChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Archive Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/archiveChat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/deleteChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Delete Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_below="@id/deleteChat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view3"
        android:id="@+id/markAsUnread"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Mark as unread"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/markAsUnread"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view4"
        android:id="@+id/emailChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Email Chat"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```