# setAdapter is showing NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I want to open a dialog for user to choose from multiple items but I get an error when `setAdapter()` was going to execute...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog cd = new Dialog(Main1.this);

                String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cd.getContext(), R.layout.lvlayout, mobileArray);

                 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewID);

                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                cd.setContentView(R.layout.dialogLayout);
                cd.setTitle("MEOW");
                cd.show();

            }
        });
```

`ListView` is in Dialog layout. whats Wrong here?

Comment: then use `ListView listView = (ListView) cd.findViewById(R.id.listviewID);`

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I did but didnt work.

Comment: can you check this [listview with in alert dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15762955/5955593)

Comment: Then try moving `cd.setContentView` up.

Comment: Can you post the logs here ?

Comment: adding listview in your `dialogLayout` will work as suggested by @ShreeKrishna

Comment: @ShreeKrishna thank you. I didnt see that one.

Comment: @Lucifer It's my pleasure !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply there are two mistakes in your code, you are calling this line without prefixing it with `cd.` so that you have to do it like this,

```
ListView listView = (ListView) cd.findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
```

Another mistake you are doing is calling `findViewById` before calling `setContentView()`, This may also raise NPE.

So I suggest you to move this up and re-arrange like this

```
cd.setContentView(R.layout.dialogLayout);
ListView listView = (ListView) cd.findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `listView` null is when you call `setAdapter()` on it. So the call to `findViewById()` returns null. Maybe you just used a wrong ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic mistakes here. 
The major mistake is calling the `cd.setContentView(R.layout.dialogLayout);` at the end of your code. You need to call before you want to find something in that content layout.

And the other mistake is trying to find the list. You need to get a view to find the list in that view. This might be something like this.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) cd.getView().findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
```

However, I do prefer the following solution for your problem. This might be an easier way for what you're trying to achieve.

Here's a nice example of implementing a custom dialogue. You can have a look here.
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

So, now as you're getting `NullPointerException`, `findViewById` is not returning any reference of your `ListView` I guess. So here by using the library mentioned above you can achieve this quite easily.

```
// Initialize your dialogue
MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title("MEOW")
                .customView(R.layout.dialogLayout, true)
                .positiveText(R.string.ok)
                .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();

// Now get the view of that dialogue. 
View view = dialog.getCustomView();

// Initialize the array adapter
String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cd.getContext(), R.layout.lvlayout, mobileArray);

// Get the list view and set the adapter 
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your listview outside of onClick listener.
Initializing it in onCreate() is more preferable.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    // initialize
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
}
```