# Data Entry in List View (Android)

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way I can enter some data in a Listview, but not doing it from a class, maybe from the Properties panel in Eclipse for example.

Comment: As I know (and I think it's true) you have two options to populate list view **1** from xml (resource) **2** via code: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog

Comment: are you trying to manipulate the records after the app starts or just finding an "easier" method to populate data?

Comment: Am just trying to find an easier way. Am not planning to change the data on my list view.