# How to display first character of each name in a list view in alert dialog as a circular icon?

Tags: android, dialog

I've tried as explined below, [How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog).

But unable to get the alert dialog as shown below:

[image: Dialog Image]

Im able to create a dialog with list of names. But not able to get a circular view with characters of first letter in first name and last name.

Comment: Well then you probably need to make your own xml which contains a circle and some kind of a textView in the center. And you need to set that drawable as 'drawableLeft' of your textView which shows the names of people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this only for answer this problem it works 10000% 
Please follow the step below.

work flow.

1. Method to create dialog and show.

   ```
   private void showDialog(){
   AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
   dialogBuilder.setTitle("Friends List");

   ArrayList<DialogModel> list = new ArrayList<DialogModel>();
   list.add(new DialogModel("Rafique"));
   list.add(new DialogModel("Abedin"));
   list.add(new DialogModel("Masud"));
   list.add(new DialogModel("Younus"));

   DialogAdapter dialogAdapter = new DialogAdapter(this, list);

   dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
   });
   //seting adapter to dialog
   dialogBuilder.setAdapter(dialogAdapter,null);
   //show dialog
   dialogBuilder.show();
   }
   ```
2. Code to create adapter for dialog

   ```
   private class DialogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DialogModel>{

   ArrayList<DialogModel> list;

   public DialogAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<DialogModel> objects) {
       super(context, R.layout.list, objects);
       this.list = objects;
   }

   private class ViewHolder{
       Button icon;
       TextView name;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ViewHolder viewHolder;

       if (convertView == null) {
           viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
           viewHolder.icon = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.round_icon);
           viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
              convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
              viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
       viewHolder.icon.setText(list.get(position).getName().substring(0, 1));
       viewHolder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
     }

     }
   ```
3. Model of the adapter

   ```
    private class DialogModel{

   private String name;

   DialogModel(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   }
   ```
4. XML for adapter layout
   create a layout list.xml

   ```
   <Button  android:id="@+id/round_icon"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttin" 
            android:text="B" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/> 
   <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_name" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
   ```
5. xml for round icon for the code portion  android:background="@drawable/round_button"
   create round_button.xml
   and put it in drawable folder

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;   
         <item android:state_pressed="false"> 
            <shape android:shape="oval"> 
               <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/> 
            </shape> 
         </item> 
         <item android:state_pressed="true"> 
            <shape android:shape="oval"> 
               <solid android:color="#c20586"/> 
            </shape> 
         </item>     
    </selector>
   ```

if any problem you are free to ask.

Comment: Code for step 4.    <Button
        android:id="@+id/round_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttin"
        android:text="B" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

Comment: Code for Step 5.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, add new drawable

> my_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke

        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ccc" />

</shape>
```

and add this to your customized view:

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/my_letter"
       android:textColor="#26ae90"
       android:textSize="50dp"
       android:text="A"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:background="@drawable/my_shape"/>
```

then use this code at your getview() methode of the adapter

```
my_letter.setText(String.valueOf(name.getText().toString().charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. inside the custom adapter you can use this

   image_view_myRoudnIcon.setText(mylist.get(position).getName().substring(0, 1));
   text_view_name.setText(mylist.get(position).getName());
2. use this code to get round image view in xml

   ;