# I am having error from getting contacts from phones to display in dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-contacts

```
  btn_add_from_contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_add_from_contacts, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            /* ********************* */
            phones = getActivity().getApplication().getContentResolver().query
            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

            String name,phoneNumber;

            while(phones.moveToNext()) {
                name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                Log.w("","Names: " +name+"\nPhone: "+phoneNumber);
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            /* ********************* */




        }
    });
```

Here it is the code, all I want is to display my contacts from phone as here. I am just displaying it in while loop once but it is not giving me any output. Further I am using fragment. If any one knows what's wrong with code just help me out.

Here is the Logcat:

```
03-29 09:14:29.475 16754-16759/com.example.nomanikram.epilepsyseizuredetection I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
```

03-29 09:14:31.342 16754-16754/com.example.nomanikram.epilepsyseizuredetection W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
03-29 09:14:31.343 16754-16754/com.example.nomanikram.epilepsyseizuredetection W/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=116.09668, y[0]=382.5547, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=10351594, downTime=10351588, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
03-29 09:14:31.343 16754-16754/com.example.nomanikram.epilepsyseizuredetection W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Show Your Logcat ..

Comment: `alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();` --> why you are using inside while loop

Comment: I was just testing by putting it inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility it to add all the contacts to your

```
R.layout.layout_add_from_contacts
```

(would be helpful if it is vertical linear layout). You can do that by inflating and filling separate view, like

```
R.layout.contact_item,
```

(which you need to create) for every contact, and adding it to the linear layout, which will be used as a view for the dialog window.

Other easier solution would be to use ArrayAdapter, like here:
[How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to display contacts,

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Contacts List");
        ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
        phones = getActivity().getApplication().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        String name,phoneNumber;

        while(phones.moveToNext()) {
            name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            Log.w("","Names: " +name+"\nPhone: "+phoneNumber);
            array.add(name+"-->"+phoneNumber);
        }
        builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                        //item clicked   
                        }
                    });
        builder.show();
```