# (JAVA version)AlertDialog with Listview and textbox

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I got a android app with java version(not flutter and not kotlin).
There is a AlertDialog,normally with title(setTitle) and listview(setItems).
Now I would add a editable textbox between title and listview
(Or let  the title become the textbox).

How can I do??

Thx for help~

Comment: is this your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog

Comment: Sorry,I did not see  a editable textbox between title and listview

Comment: I have added answer with editable textbox between title and listview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, custom layout for dialog

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout

Answer (score 0):

If you want an editable textbox between title and list view , then you need to create custom layout. Here is full code and its working fine as shown in image[image: here].

```
public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

    String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    alertDialog.setView(convertView);
    alertDialog.setTitle("List");
    ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    alertDialog.show();
}}
```

Here is custom list_item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Edit Text Here"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```